# Сравнения чисел в разных системах используя схему Горнера

Tags: c

Нужно сравнить 2 числа в одной системе счисления, числа ввести нужно как строки, возможные системы от 2 до 16

Превод в int

```
int CharToInt(char *s) {
  int result = 0;
  result = (int)s - (int)'0';
  if( result<0 || result>9){ // для 16 системи обработка А-F
        result = (int)s - (int)'0' - 7;
    }
  return result;
}
```

Перевод в 10 систему для сравнения

```
int ToDec(char *number,int systemNumber){
    int result = 0;             //результат
    int length = strlen(number),// к-во чисел в строке
                 i,             //счетчик цикла
                 c_str=0;           //счетчик для строки
    int step = length-1;        //степень в какую возводим

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        result += CharToInt(number[c_str]) * pow(systemNumber,step);//1 *10^2+0*10^1+0*10^0
        step--; // уменьшаем степень
        c_str++; //next цифра
    }
    return result;
}
```

При значениях `ToDec("100",10)` почему-то возвращает 99 вместо 100

Comment: Пора брать в руки отладчик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил ошибку компиляции. Нужно изменить сигнатуру функции CharToInt на

```
int CharToInt(char s)
```

До этого указатель на char воспринимался как C-style строка, а не символ.

```
Result: 100.
```

Comment: Странно, у меня все равно возвращает 99, указатель убрал.

Comment: Да, прошелся отладчиком - все нормально работает. Попробуйте тоже в дебаггере посмотреть корректность работы

Comment: Скомпилировал в VS 2013 - все работает как нужно - 100.
В CodeBlocks возвращает 99. Как я понимаю дело в компиляторе.

Comment: Очень странно. В CodeBlocks можно трассировать код? Посмотреть, почему именно такое значение получилось